# Optimizing vector indexing and matrix creation in R

Tags: r, optimization, vector, matrix, indexing

first of all I am sorry if this topic has already been discussed somewhere else but I could not find anything relevant when searching.

My problem is the following:
I have 4 vectors with partially overlapping names and I want to organize all these data into a matrix. I want the final matrix to have an entry for all the names present in at least one of the input vectors. I used the following code.

```
IDs <- unique(c(names(v1), names(v2), names(v3), names(v4))) 
mat <- matrix(c(v1[IDs], v2[IDs], v3[IDs], v4[IDs]), nrow=length(IDs), ncol=4)
mat[is.na(mat)] <- 0 
# This last line is to convert NAs generated when the entry isn't present in all vectors into 0 values.
```

It works well but, as I have a total of entries > 2.2 millions, this is extremely slow (it took 2.5 days to run...). I am thus looking for a way to speed up the process.

I tried to use other structures (e.g. to create a data frame instead of a matrix) but without great improvement. After some tests, it seems that the bottleneck is the following step (even when considered individually):

```
v1[IDs]
```

which is repeated for each of the vectors (1 to 4). Note that typically only ~50% of the names overlap between two vectors  (and therefore that only 50% of IDs/names used for indexing are initially present in the names of the vector).

I monitored a bit the CPU and memory used  during the process and it seems that it is not a memory issue (the 6 free Gb remained free during the process).

I would appreciate any hint on how to make this process faster. As I have to repeat this process several times, I can't really afford to wait 2 days each time I have to generate such an object.

Thanks. =)

Philippe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `reshape2` package, the `dcast` function can do the job.
First stack your vectors in a `data.frame`:

```
df <- rbind(data.frame(IDs=names(v1), value=v1, vec=1),
data.frame(IDs=names(v2), value=v2, vec=2),
data.frame(IDs=names(v3), value=v3, vec=3),
data.frame(IDs=names(v4), value=v4, vec=4))
```

Then transform this in a wide format:

```
dcast(df, ids ~ vec, value.var="value")
```

This outputs a `data.frame` but you can easily convert it back to a `matrix`

The speedup seems to increase as `N` grows: 5x faster with `N=5000`, 30x faster with `N=10000`, 67x faster with `N=50000` where `N` is the length of `v1`.

Comment: Works perfectly thanks! The code ran in less than a minute. As a comparison, this is the amount of time I needed to process about 50k entries (out of 2.2 millions) using my initial method...